# Apache rewrite rule to proxy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I need apache to rewrite and proxy (both http and ws)

```
http://example.com/dir/1234/argument/foo/bar
```

to

```
http://localhost:1234/argument/foo/bar.
```

I have tried these rewrite rules (at .htaccess in dir):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\/(\d*)\/(.*)$  http://localhost:$2/$1/$3 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\/(\d*)\/(.*)$  ws://localhost:$2/$1/$3 [P,L]
```

But getting an internal error (500) from apache.

Any suggestions?

### Update

I solved the problem. Since the .htaccess is in `dir` I have to match the rest of the url - hence `1234/argument/foo/bar`.

So the rewrite rule is just:

```
RewriteRule (\d*)\/([^\/.]*)(\/.*)  http://localhost:$1/$2/$3 [P,L]
```

Comment: 500 errors are always accompanied by an error lot message which will tell you what the problem is and often how to fix it

Comment: If there is no error message (or a not sufficient message), increase the log verbosity to maximum. See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel